# A script that runs a command based on selected artwork colors

Tags: javascript, adobe-illustrator

I tried to make a script that will do an action a couple of times (loop) based on the number of colors that the selected art have.
And if there is a way to store the color names in an array it would be great too.

I can't figure it out on my own and I only have the basics of the script:

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var sel = doc.selection[0];
var selcolors = 0;

//====================
//Here I need to get how many colors the selected art have and set it to selcolors
//====================

for(i = 0; i < selcolors; i++)
{
   //Set of actions
}
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Example of my graphics:
[image]

Comment: Can you show a screenshot how your art looks like? Do you mean to select several object and get their colors? Or you have one object with several fill or/and stroke colors?

Comment: I edited my post and added a picture.
All my graphics are contained in a group. it may have several fill/stroke colors depend on the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what exactly you're trying to do with the colors and what kind of colors you're using.

For example for spot colors it can be something like this:

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var sel = doc.selection;

// get all path items from the selection
var pathItems = [];
for (var i=0; i<sel.length; i++) get_all_pathItems(sel[i], pathItems);

// put all the colors into the object
var obj = {};
for (var i=0; i<pathItems.length; i++) {
    var item = pathItems[i];
    if (item.filled) {
        var color = item.fillColor;
        if (color instanceof SpotColor) obj[color.spot.name] = color;
    }
    if (item.stroked) {
        var color = item.strokeColor;
        if (color instanceof SpotColor) obj[color.spot.name] = color;
    }
}

// get a number of the colors from the object 
var n = 0;
for (key in obj) n++;

// updated lines below:

// run some actions, perhaps you don't even need the number
for (key in obj) {
    if (key == 'White') continue; // skip White color
    // action 1
    // action 2
    // etc...
}

// ----------------------------------------------------------

// recursive function to fill the given array with all pathItems of given item
function get_all_pathItems(item, arr) {
    try { if (item instanceof PathItem) arr.push(item) } catch(e) {}
    try {
        if (item instanceof GroupItem) {
            var paths = item.pathItems;
            for (var i=0; i<paths.length; i++) arr.push(paths[i]);
            var groups = item.groupItems;
            for (var i=0; i<groups.length; i++) get_all_pathItems(groups[i], arr);
        }
    } catch(e) {}
}
```

And there is one problem. In Illustrator a group of items can have its own color (fill and stroke). As far as I know you can't get the color of the group with a script. A script can get only colors of a path items, not groups.

**Update**

Here is the the updated code that selects objects with the same color of fill or stroke and do actions in the loop:

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var sel = doc.selection;

// get all path items from the selection
var pathItems = [];
for (var i=0; i<sel.length; i++) get_all_pathItems(sel[i], pathItems);

// put all the colors into the object
var obj = {};
for (var i=0; i<pathItems.length; i++) {
    var item = pathItems[i];
    if (item.filled) {
        var color = item.fillColor;
        if (color instanceof SpotColor) obj[color.spot.name] = color;
    }
    if (item.stroked) {
        var color = item.strokeColor;
        if (color instanceof SpotColor) obj[color.spot.name] = color;
    }
}

delete obj['White'] // remove White from the object

// add empty arrays to every color in the object
for (color in obj) obj[color].items = [];

// fill the arrays of the object with items of the same fill or stroke color
for (var i=0; i<pathItems.length; i++) {
    var item = pathItems[i];
    if (item.filled) {
        var color = item.fillColor;
        if (color instanceof SpotColor) {
            if (color.spot.name in obj) obj[color.spot.name].items.push(item);
        }
    }
    if (item.stroked) {
        var color = item.strokeColor;
        if (color instanceof SpotColor) {
            if (color.spot.name in obj) obj[color.spot.name].items.push(item);
        }
    }
}

for (color in obj) {
    app.selection = obj[color].items; // select all object from the color's array
    // do action with the selected objects
}


// ----------------------------------------------------------

// recursive function to fill the given array with all pathItems of given item
function get_all_pathItems(item, arr) {
    try { if (item instanceof PathItem) arr.push(item) } catch(e) {}
    try {
        if (item instanceof GroupItem) {
            var paths = item.pathItems;
            for (var i=0; i<paths.length; i++) arr.push(paths[i]);
            var groups = item.groupItems;
            for (var i=0; i<groups.length; i++) get_all_pathItems(groups[i], arr);
        }
    } catch(e) {}
}
```

Just in case. If you need to get the "collective" size (width and height) of the items with the same color you can do something like this:

```
// loop through the colors and get sizes of items with the same colors
var report = [];

for (color in obj) {
    var items = obj[color].items
    var size = get_size(items);

    report.push([
        'Color: '           + color,
        'Number of items: ' + items.length,
        'Width: '           + size.width,
        'Height: '          + size.height,
    ].join('\n'));
}

alert(report.join('\n\n')); // show the report

// ------------------------------------------------------------------
// function to get the collective size {width, height} of given items
function get_size(array) {
    var tops = [], lefts = [], rights = [], bottoms = [];

    for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i].guides) continue; // skip guides just in case
           tops.push(array[i].visibleBounds[1]);
          lefts.push(array[i].visibleBounds[0]);
         rights.push(array[i].visibleBounds[2]);
        bottoms.push(array[i].visibleBounds[3]);
    };

    var top    = Math.max.apply(null, tops);
    var left   = Math.min.apply(null, lefts);
    var right  = Math.max.apply(null, rights);
    var bottom = Math.min.apply(null, bottoms);

    return {width:right-left, height:bottom-top};
}
```

It will show you the sizes (the alert window) for every spot color of selected artwork. Of course you can save the report into a text file as well.

---

**Update 2**

Here is the full implementation of the code which draws marks for every spot color of selected items. The code considered masks and text objects. The marks are aligned by the center of top selected object.

```
if (app.activeDocument.selection.length != 0) main();

function main() {

    // disable warnings
    var uInterration = app.userInteractionLevel;
    app.userInteractionLevel = UserInteractionLevel.DONTDISPLAYALERTS;

    // save selection and deselect all
    var orig_selection = app.selection;
    app.selection = null;

    // duplicate the objects that were selected and select the duplicates
    var duplicates = [];
    for (var i=0; i<orig_selection.length; i++) duplicates.push(orig_selection[i].duplicate());
    app.selection = duplicates;

    // UPDATED get the horizontal and vertical axes for the marks from the top object
    var top_object = app.selection[0];
    if (top_object.clipped || top_object instanceof GroupItem) {
        var top_inner_object = top_object.pageItems[0];
        if (top_inner_object.clipped) top_object = top_inner_object.pageItems[0];
    }
    var vertical_axis   = top_object.position[0] + top_object.width/2;
    var horizontal_axis = top_object.position[1] - top_object.height/2;

    // expand the selected objects
    // ungroup all groups, flat all masks, outline texts, release compound paths)
    expand_selected_items();

    // create the object with colors and pathItems
    var obj = make_color_object(app.activeDocument.selection);

    // loop through the object and make the marks for every color
    for (color in obj) {
        var size = get_size(obj[color].items); // get sizes
        draw_marks(size, horizontal_axis, vertical_axis, obj[color]);
    }

    // remove the temp objects and restore the original selection
    for (var i=app.selection.length-1; i>=0; i--) app.selection[i].remove();
    app.selection = orig_selection;

    // restore warnings
    app.userInteractionLevel = uInterration;

}

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// function returns the 'collective' size and edges of given array of items
// {left, top, right, bottom, width, height}
function get_size(items) {
    var tops = [], lefts = [], rights = [], bottoms = [];

    for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
        if (items[i].guides) continue;
           tops.push(items[i].visibleBounds[1]);
          lefts.push(items[i].visibleBounds[0]);
         rights.push(items[i].visibleBounds[2]);
        bottoms.push(items[i].visibleBounds[3]);
    };

    var top    = Math.max.apply(null, tops);
    var left   = Math.min.apply(null, lefts);
    var right  = Math.max.apply(null, rights);
    var bottom = Math.min.apply(null, bottoms);

    return {left:left, top:top, right:right, bottom:bottom, width:right-left, height:top-bottom};
}

// function 'expands' all selected objects
// (releases masks and compound paths, ungroups groups, outlines strokes and texts)
function expand_selected_items() {
    app.executeMenuCommand('ungroup');
    app.executeMenuCommand('ungroup');
    app.executeMenuCommand('outline');                // text to curves
    app.executeMenuCommand('ungroup');
    app.executeMenuCommand('OffsetPath v22');         // expand stroke
    app.executeMenuCommand('Live Pathfinder Divide'); // expand masks (Live)
    app.executeMenuCommand('expandStyle');            // Live --> plain
    app.executeMenuCommand('noCompoundPath');         // release compound paths
    app.executeMenuCommand('ungroup');
}

// function makes the color object from given array of pathItems:
// {color1:{color, items:[pathItems]}, color2:{color, items:[pathItems]}, ...}
function make_color_object(items) {
    var obj = {};

    var add_color_into_obj = function(color, obj) {
        if (color instanceof SpotColor)
            obj[color.spot.name] = color;
    }

    var put_item_into_color = function(color, obj, item) {
        if (color instanceof SpotColor && color.spot.name in obj)
            obj[color.spot.name].items.push(item);
    }

    // add colors into the object
    for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
        if (items[i].filled) add_color_into_obj(items[i].fillColor, obj);
        // if (items[i].stroked) add_color_into_obj(items[i].strokeColor, obj); // there is no stroked objects anyway
    }

    delete obj['White']; // remove White color from the object

    // add empty arrays to every color in the object
    for (color in obj) obj[color].items = [];

    // fill the arrays of the object with items of the same fill or stroke color
    for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
        if (items[i].filled) put_item_into_color(items[i].fillColor, obj, items[i]);
        // if (items[i].stroked) put_item_into_color(items[i].strokeColor, obj, items[i]); // there is no stroked objects anyway
    }

    return obj;
}

// function draws the four marks around the given area
// the marks will be aligned by the given horizontal and vertical axes
function draw_marks(area, horiz, vert, color) {
    var mm = 2.83464566929134; // mm/pt
    var space = 5 * mm;
    var len = 3 * mm;
    var strokeWidth = 1; // pt
    var x1,x2,y1,y2;

    // select or make the group
    var group_name = 'Marks';
    try {
        var group = app.activeDocument.groupItems.getByName(group_name) }
    catch(e) {
        var group = app.activeDocument.groupItems.add();
        group.name = group_name;
    }

    // subfunction to draw the mark with given coords
    var draw_mark = function(x1,y1,x2,y2,label) {
        var mark = app.activeDocument.pathItems.add();
            mark.setEntirePath([[x1,y1],[x2,y2]]);
            mark.filled = false;
            mark.stroked = true;
            mark.strokeWidth = strokeWidth;
            mark.strokeOverprint = true;
            mark.strokeColor = color;

            mark.name = color.spot.name + ' - ' + label;
        return mark;
    }

    y1 = y2 = horiz;
    x1 = area.left - len - space;
    x2 = x1 + len;
    draw_mark(x1,y1,x2,y2,'left').moveToEnd(group);

    x1 = area.right + space;
    x2 = x1 + len;
    draw_mark(x1,y1,x2,y2,'right').moveToEnd(group);

    x1 = x2 = vert;
    y1 = area.top + space + len;
    y2 = y1 - len;
    draw_mark(x1,y1,x2,y2,'top').moveToEnd(group);

    y1 = area.bottom - space;
    y2 = y1 - len;
    draw_mark(x1,y1,x2,y2,'bottom').moveToEnd(group);
}
```

Result (the dashed lines were added manually to show the logic behind the mark positions):

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! That's exactly how I wanted it. Is there a way that if it detects "White" it will not count it?

Comment: Most likely you can omit "White" by two ways. Check the name: `if (key != "White") ...`. And/or to check the CMYK-percents of the color. I'll show you how it can be done. Basically `obj[key].spot.color.cyan` is number of % of Cyan,  `obj[key].spot.color.magenta` is a number of % of Magenta, etc.

Comment: I added this line to the code "if (key == "White") {n--;}" but it only work for fill color and not stroke. How can I fix it? I'm not familiar with all those key stuff, It's above my level.

Comment: See my updated code. I've added the line `if (obj[key].spot.name == 'White') continue;` inside the loop to skip the color with name White and it works fine with fills and strokes on my test file. And I added the `try/catch` into the function, since it can get me sometimes the error if there is no groups (as far as I can tell, on my CS6 at least).

Comment: And probably you don't need the `n` counter to run the actions. You can iterate directly trough the keys of the object.

Comment: `if (key == 'White')` is the same as `if (obj[key].spot.name == 'White')` in this case

Comment: Thank you so much it works! I need the n counter for another thing so it will help me in the future.
What I'm trying to do is making a selection of the objects of the color it's checking (fill or stroke) and do an action to them and then move on to the next color and do the same.

So now we know how many colors the selection have but I can't find a way to make a selection of each color and execute a set of actions.

Comment: I don't get from your last comment if still you need a help?

Comment: Yes, the loop that makes the actions, I need it to select the all the objects with the color that it's checking and store their collective width and height.

Comment: I just added the updated version of the code. It selects the objects with the same fill or stroke color and then you can do your action with the objects. As for the "checking and store their collective width and height" -- do you mean you have already the action or code for this or do you need to make it?

Comment: I already made the code that I want to use but my problem now is that I can't access the current selection and use it's properties.

here is a part of my code:
`sym1.top = sel.top+50;`

It does not find the selection to adjust the top position of a rectangle that I make. Can't figure out how to access the current selection.

my code will create rectangles based on the number of colors in the first selection and then will position them in the places that I want them to be according to the new selections.

Comment: Illustrator's script API has no native tool to get coordinates (top corner, left corner, width, height, or geometricBounds) for several selected objects. You have to compute these properties by yourself, to loop trough the objects and figure out which of the objects is most left one or most right one, etc. My function `get_size(array)` does exactly this. You can pass the array of objects and get their summarized coordinates. It returns width and height now, but you can change the return with anything you need. For example: `return {top, left, bottom, right};`

Comment: `return {left:left, top:top, width:right-left, height:top-bottom}`. And then in the main loop something like: `var box = doc.pathItems.rectangle(size.top, size.left, size.width, size.height, false);` Here is my updated code:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1txX4-YhKSeNKmXCuG0JVWgRakwOatkqf/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you so much! I made it to work as I wanted it to but I found 2 problems:
 1. It does not count text in the calculation.
 2. I have a problem with clipping masks (It's not a problem of the script but maybe you know how to solve it) that when I create the rectangle it uses the whole clipped item sizes instead the clipping mask size.
here is my code:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DpBZ_qIFxtPZjT2z5qzaSx6O2cPEtTMh/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The problems can be solved if you make a temporary copy of the selected objects, outline the texts, expand the masks, run the rest of the code for these temporary objects (as if it's a usual selection) and remove the temp objects at the end. I've added the several lines into your Script.jsx and it seems it does the trick well. Here is the updated script: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EczLtM_DXTN0FdlhfK43ISiVeAWz6-VP/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I didn't change the rest code. Since I'm not quite understand the logic of the marks, I'm not sure if they work correctly. Probably it will need some additional tweaks with the variables `selfirst`, `selhcen`, `selvcen`, because the dimension of the original selected object can differ from the dimension of the same objects after expanding.

Comment: Just it case, I've looked your code more closely and I think I figured out what exactly it supposed to do. It does the job more or less, but there are some nasty problems with stroked and compound paths. So, after all, I decided to rewrite it completely. Here is the new version: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RX7Zuj0O1SSwMIdh5I4eLqgQm47ypVIT/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I tried it with complex compound path of a bowl with fruits and it just crashed illustrator, probably because it's checking for every path inside it. Then I tried it with bunch of texts and it had a weird reaction. Here is what happened:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FB8DOE3fugsdsqWdZQIOrPtvlfr-FG7z/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QdjkqxQLEcMmzJUcu33nm3HwXqNMPKQc/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hqx5lFzSImxlHh1VWLZP8clMPxE1EQNe/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I found a script that does what I need but it's too complex and it does check for the colors but maybe the solutions can come from there:
https://sites.google.com/site/dtpscripting/illustrator-scripts/makecropmarksai

Comment: The warning windows can be disabled. If you click 'OK' it will run fine. Or, most likely, it can be done automatically inside a script.

Comment: As for the marks position: there is one thing in your script that I don't understand. It takes the first (top) object from the selection and aligns the marks by center of this object. It gives the strange result sometimes (especially if the first objects just one of elements of the artworks). I don't know if you really mean it? If you don't mean it the behavior can be changed pretty easy. But you have to show a couple examples: what desired result should look like.

Comment: In the script that I found I meant to say that it does not check for the colors, that's why I'm not using it.

In my script I check for the first selection measuers because all the lines needs to be centered by it but the position will be 5 mm away from the colors that we are checking for.

Comment: If there is a way to add the color checking for the script that I found and let it make more lines for other colors it will be great too.

Comment: I've added a couple lines into my variant of the script to suppress the warnings messages. The script is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1omBFVxTREro2pAXXSxF0cxRTpykfX7GE/view?usp=sharing Try it. As for the weird reactions and crashes: I can't reproduce it on my files. If you provide a sample of your atrwork I could try to figure out where is the problem.

Comment: You can ask Segey Anosov first, the author of the script, if he can to add a couple features into his script: https://sites.google.com/site/dtpscripting/contacts

Comment: Amazing!
2 Things that still needs to be fixed:
1. When there are items in clipping masks the marks are not centered to the first selection but to global size of the items under the clipping masks.

2. When the job have a very complex compound paths it takes a lot of time and illustrator stop working.

picture to the first problem:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V54niUyoR67uxw5uYufsk84zDXmLDFHL/view?usp=sharing

A file with complex compound path item (texts were outlined):
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fPCjPp4oPEKbTs5y0nQEOYzxBLqMQPpl/view?usp=sharing

Comment: For big complicated graphics I have no good solution. ~23K+ paths it's too much. Probably you have to reduce the complexity manually. In this case I've added .1pt outline, expanded and united (Pathfinder) the picture in the middle. This way I got ~700 paths and scripts handled them just fine. Here is the corrected file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VnJkf77zFc8RfXocqNKnUKhR0yAHkKYE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: As for (1) clipping mask… Could you provide the file? The screenshot looks like a result of 'Draw Behind' mode. Probably it will be enough to change the line: `var top_object_size = get_size([app.selection[0]]);` with `var top_object = app.selection[0]; if (top_object.clipped) top_object = top_object.pathItems[0]; var top_object_size = get_size([top_object]);`

Comment: I just updated my answer. You can copy the code from there.

Comment: It didn't solve the problem with the clipping mask. That is why in my earlier script I made "selfirst" to remember to size of the real selection and then it's just make to top and bottom to be centered horizontally to the selection and the left and right vertically to the selection. I managed to fix that. Here is a link to the file with the clipping: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1N4QAmh9d9ZOxJEUx45KzwTBX0C0j2-ka/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I will still do more testings but so far it's working as expected.

Comment: I just updated the last example of this variant of the code. The part that gets the axes. Based on your file. Try it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time! I did a few tests with different jobs that I had. It works exactly as I need! I found a glitch that when you have clipping masks inside a group a pair of the marks not located at the center of the selection. It's not a big deal and I can live with that but here is the file for you to test it by yourself: https://drive.google.com/file/d/12XAioKUmWM86RaZUyWE6e0T18OMy0Fec/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I really appreciate your work, I struggled with this script for over a year now. Couldn't do it by myself.

Comment: Hi, sorry to bother you again but after testing a lot more projects of many kinds I found out that sometimes it have problems with texts, it ignores them sometimes. here is a sample file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iqXN_TKnx8G7LCiEm1Yf2ihMFLEJi492/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi, in this particular file the text has the non-spot fill (CMYK 0,0,0,100). The script ignores all non-spot colors. As soon as I applied a spot-color fill ('Line' or 'Black') the script makes the marks as it was supposed.

Comment: Oh, my bad, I didn't check for the colors of the objects. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach that probably works better for complex graphics. It calculates the size of selected objects via changing the size of artboard (`Object` > `Artboard` > `Fit to Selected Art`). It selects the objects with the same fill color via the native Illustrator function (`Select` > `Same` > `Fill Color`). This way there is no need to iterate through all the thousands pathItems.

```
if (app.selection.length != 0) main();

function main() {

    // disable warnings
    var uil = app.userInteractionLevel;
    app.userInteractionLevel = UserInteractionLevel.DONTDISPLAYALERTS;

    // make copy of selected items and lock the original items
    app.copy();
    app.executeMenuCommand('lock');
    app.executeMenuCommand('pasteInPlace');

    // get the horizontal and vertical axes for the marks from the top object
    var top_object = app.selection[0];
    if (top_object.clipped) top_object = top_object.pathItems[0];
    var vertical_axis   = top_object.position[0] + top_object.width/2;
    var horizontal_axis = top_object.position[1] - top_object.height/2;

    // outline texts, expand masks, expand strokes
    expand_selected_items();

    // collect all spot colors of the document
    var colors = get_spot_colors();

    // loop through spots
    for (var i=0; i<colors.length; i++) {
        select_items_by_color(colors[i]); // select items by the fill color
        if (app.selection.length == 0) continue;
        var size = get_size_of_selection(); // get sizes
        draw_marks(size, horizontal_axis, vertical_axis, colors[i]);
    }

    // remove all the new unlocked items and unlock original items
    app.executeMenuCommand('selectall');
    app.executeMenuCommand('clear');
    app.executeMenuCommand('unlockAll');

    // restore warnings
    app.userInteractionLevel = uil;

}

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// function return array of all spot colors of current document
function get_spot_colors() {
    var colors = [];
    var doc = app.activeDocument;
    for (var i=2; i<doc.swatches.length; i++) {
        if (doc.swatches[i].color.spot) colors.push(doc.swatches[i].color);
    }
    return colors;
}

// functin selects all objects that have given fillColor
function select_items_by_color(color) {
    var box = app.activeDocument.pathItems.rectangle(0,0,1,1);
    box.filled = true;
    box.fillColor = color;
    app.selection = null;
    box.selected = true;
    app.executeMenuCommand('Find Fill Color menu item'); // select items with thw same fill color
    box.remove();
}

// functon return size of selected items
function get_size_of_selection() {
    var doc = app.activeDocument;
    var orig_rect = doc.artboards[0].artboardRect;
    app.executeMenuCommand('Fit Artboard to selected Art'); // change artboard size by selection
    var rect = doc.artboards[0].artboardRect;
    doc.artboards[0].artboardRect = orig_rect;
    var l = rect[0], t = rect[1]; // left, right
    var r = rect[2], b = rect[3]; // top, bottom
    var w = r-l, h = t-b;         // width, height
    return { left:l, right:r, top:t, bottom:b, width:w, height:h }
}

// function 'expands' all selected objects
function expand_selected_items() {
    app.executeMenuCommand('ungroup');
    app.executeMenuCommand('ungroup');
    app.executeMenuCommand('outline');              // text to curves
    app.executeMenuCommand('ungroup');
    app.executeMenuCommand('OffsetPath v22');       // expand stroke
    app.executeMenuCommand('expandStyle');
    app.executeMenuCommand('Live Pathfinder Crop'); // expand masks
    app.executeMenuCommand('expandStyle');
    app.executeMenuCommand('noCompoundPath');       // release compound paths
    app.executeMenuCommand('ungroup');
}

// function draws the four marks around the given area
// the marks will be aligned by the given horizontal and vertical axes
function draw_marks(area, h_axis, v_axis, color) {
    var mm = 2.83464566929134; // mm/pt
    var space = 5 * mm;
    var len = 3 * mm;
    var strokeWidth = 1; // pt
    var x1,x2,y1,y2;

    // select or make the group
    var group_name = 'Marks';
    try {
        var group = app.activeDocument.groupItems.getByName(group_name) }
    catch(e) {
        var group = app.activeDocument.groupItems.add();
        group.name = group_name;
    }

    // subfunction to draw the mark with given coords
    var draw_mark = function(x1,y1,x2,y2,label) {
        var mark = app.activeDocument.pathItems.add();
            mark.setEntirePath([[x1,y1],[x2,y2]]);
            mark.filled = false;
            mark.stroked = true;
            mark.strokeWidth = strokeWidth;
            mark.strokeColor = color;
            mark.strokeOverprint = true;
            mark.locked = true;
            mark.name = color.spot.name + ' - ' + label;
        return mark;
    }

    y1 = y2 = h_axis;
    x1 = area.left - len - space; x2 = x1 + len;
    draw_mark(x1,y1,x2,y2,'left').moveToEnd(group);

    x1 = area.right + space; x2 = x1 + len;
    draw_mark(x1,y1,x2,y2,'right').moveToEnd(group);

    x1 = x2 = v_axis;
    y1 = area.top + space + len; y2 = y1 - len;
    draw_mark(x1,y1,x2,y2,'top').moveToEnd(group);

    y1 = area.bottom - space; y2 = y1 - len;
    draw_mark(x1,y1,x2,y2,'bottom').moveToEnd(group);
}
```

It supposed to give the same result as the code in my first answer.

Comment: It does work better with complex graphics but It does not work with texts for some reason so I can't really use it.

Comment: I works fine with text objects on my test files: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIpvZ.png . Can you provide the a sample from your file?

Comment: I just tried with CC2023 and it seems it works differently from CS6. And CC2023 looks pretty buggy. It sometimes works, sometimes doesn't on exactly the same file (even with simplest graphic) and same code. And sometimes it crashes after Ctrl+Z or Ctrl+Alt+7 (release a mask) for example. The famous Illustrator engine. (

Comment: I have the feeling its behavior can somehow depends on if there are another opened files in Illustrator.

Comment: And the messing around with the system clipboard (`app.copy()`, `app.paste()`, etc) is a source of strange glitches quite often.